# porting a function from matlab to python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

I am trying to port the following Function from matlab to python:

```
function J = do_localmax(octave, thresh,smin)

[N,M,S]=size(octave); 
nb=1;
k=0.0002;

J = [];
for s=2:S-1
for j=20:M-20
    for i=20:N-20
        a=octave(i,j,s);

        if a>thresh+k ...
                && a>octave(i-1,j-1,s-1)+k && a>octave(i-1,j,s-1)+k && a>octave(i-1,j+1,s-1)+k ...
                && a>octave(i,j-1,s-1)+k && a>octave(i,j+1,s-1)+k && a>octave(i+1,j-1,s-1)+k ...
                && a>octave(i+1,j,s-1)+k && a>octave(i+1,j+1,s-1)+k && a>octave(i-1,j-1,s)+k ...
                && a>octave(i-1,j,s)+k && a>octave(i-1,j+1,s)+k && a>octave(i,j-1,s)+k ...
                && a>octave(i,j+1,s)+k && a>octave(i+1,j-1,s)+k && a>octave(i+1,j,s)+k ...
                && a>octave(i+1,j+1,s)+k && a>octave(i-1,j-1,s+1)+k && a>octave(i-1,j,s+1)+k ...
                && a>octave(i-1,j+1,s+1)+k && a>octave(i,j-1,s+1)+k && a>octave(i,j+1,s+1)+k ...
                && a>octave(i+1,j-1,s+1)+k && a>octave(i+1,j,s+1)+k && a>octave(i+1,j+1,s+1)+k
        %if (a-maximum>0.00004)
        %if (a-maximum>0.001)
            J(1,nb)=j-1;
            J(2,nb)=i-1;
            J(3,nb)=s+smin-1;
            nb=nb+1;
        end
    end
end
end
```

and this is what I got:

```
def localmax(Tmpo, thresh,smin,nb):

diff0= numpy.array(diff0)

M= len(Tmpo[:,0,0])
N= len(Tmpo[0,:,0])
T= len(Tmpo[0,0,:])
k=0.0002;

#%for each point of this scale space
#% we look for extrama bigger than thresh

J=numpy.zeros((4,1000))

for s in range(0,T-1):
    for j in range(20,N-20):
        for i in range(20,M-20):
            a=Tmpo[i,j,s]

            if a>thresh+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i-1,j-1,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j+1,s-1]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i,j-1,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i,j+1,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j-1,s-1]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i+1,j,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j+1,s-1]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j-1,s]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i-1,j,s]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j+1,s]+k and a>Tmpo[i,j-1,s]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i,j+1,s]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j-1,s]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j,s]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i+1,j+1,s]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j-1,s+1]+k and a>Tmpo[i-1,j,s+1]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i-1,j+1,s+1]+k and a>Tmpo[i,j-1,s+1]+k and a>Tmpo[i,j+1,s+1]+k \
                and a>Tmpo[i+1,j-1,s+1]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j,s+1]+k and a>Tmpo[i+1,j+1,s+1]+k:

                print 'we are here'
                J[0,nb]=(j-1)
                J[1,nb]=(i-1)
                J[2,nb]=(s+smin-1)
                nb += 1

J=J[numpy.nonzero(J)]

return J
```

whenever I try to implement it it returns am empty array given the fact that I see the print statement in my python shell. Any help?

Comment: Are you indenting the code within the function. The function `def` and the code start on the same column.

Can you also print the value of (j-1), (i-1) etc, when you print "we are here" to make sure they are not 0s.

Comment: yes i tried printing the values and its fine. i see j-1 and the other values increasing

Comment: Have you debugged and compared them line for line?

Comment: Can you provide a sample `Tmpo` array, and values for `thresh,smin,nb`? I can't test it locally right now.

Comment: nb=0 , thresh=0.8, smin=-1, and tempo is a 3D array with size (240,320,5).

Comment: I created a random 3D array of size 240,320,5, which gave me index errors. I changed J to be a array of (4, 224000) (because nb can be 4 * 280 * 200) (i.e. `J=numpy.zeros((4,224000))`) and got a non-empty result. My result had 24586 non-zero elements.

Comment: Also you can use numpy's shape function to get lengths. `M, N, T = numpy.shape(Tmpo)`